# Закругление PasswordBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Столкнулся с проблемой, нужно было закруглить `PasswordBox`, но к сожалению не получалось использовать способ от `TextBox`.

Comment: Если вы нашли ответ на свой вопрос, то его стоит убрать из вопроса и добавить в ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге смог нарыть и сделать супер короткий и колхозный `Xaml` код.

```
<PasswordBox>
    <PasswordBox.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type PasswordBox}" TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
                        <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#498C51">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </PasswordBox.Resources>
</PasswordBox>
```

В `Border` можете изменить значения под себя `CornerRadius`,   `BorderThickness`, `BorderBrush`. Ну или добавить свои приколы, всем удачи!